# how to plot in different frame in matlab

Tags: matlab

In my program, I want to get three plots ,

```
plot(CumulativeReward)
title('Cumulative Reward, gamma=1');
xlabel('episode number');
ylabel('CumulativeReward')

plot(Pathlength)
title('pathlength as a function of episode number');
xlabel('episode number');
ylabel('pathlength')

x = -pi:.1:pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y)
```

but all three plots are together in one frame, how can I put each plot in different frame box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `figure` before calling `plot`. This will open a new figure window.

In order to more easily distinguish the windows, you can set their title, for example

```
figure('name','Cumulative Reward')
```

If you want plots side-by-side, you can use `subplot`, i.e.

```
subplot(1,3,1)
%# your first plot here
subplot(1,3,2)
%# your second plot here
subplot(1,3,3)
#% your third plot here
```